# How do I prevent excessive nesting of tags in XAML?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2008, code-formatting, code-readability

Consider the following code where a cell's color changes depending on whatever (attributes stripped for brevity):

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger>
                                                    <Setter>
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                <GradientStop/>
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Are there any advanced techniques in XAML that go beyond reducing indentation from 4 to 2 and trying to shove as much stuff as I can into the top level (UserControl's in this case) resource dictionary?

PS: I'm stuck with VS 2008.

Comment: Put the `DataTemplate` as a `Resource` in the `UserControl.Resources`, then `<GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource theTemplate/>`

Comment: One simple thing you could do would be do declare the `DataTemplate` as a resource, and then reference it using a `{StaticResource}` mark-up extension.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Resources to simplify your XAML.  It also makes for better reuse and organization.  For example, with the above XAML you could break it apart into the following:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyBrush">
           <GradientStop/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <Style x:Key="ItemTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MyBrush}"/>
              </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
          <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="MyListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
          <Setter Property="View">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate}"/>
                </GridView>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView Style="{DynamicResource MyListViewStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```